# There are two different "apps" called "Add or remove programs" in Windows 10. Why? Which should I use, what are their differences?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

Let's explain it better and easy: Please, do this two things:

1. Control panel > Program > Uninstall a program (possibly under the title "Programs and features")
2. Settings > System > Apps & Features.

Now, this two routes take me to very similar applications. In both the purpose is to uninstall programs. What are their differences?
My concern is that a OS is supposed to be consistent and succinct. However there is two different applications to do such a basic task? Ok, what can be bad about having two ways instead of one, or worst zero? Well, it's disorganized, I don't know which to use and that confounds me. I don't know how Microsoft expects me to figure out which to use.

By the way, 2) also can be found by typing "add or remove program" in windows search.
And 1) says "Uninstall or change a program" in it's window.
So, both offer the ability to uninstall.

Comment: They're functionally identical for the most part and you're free to use either. One is the legacy Control Panel applet, the other is part of the Settings app.

Comment: Again, is the question answered or not? If it is answered, mark it is answered: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: I just had an application that was listed in both, but got an error when uninstalling through the new "Apps & Features", but uninstalled fine through the old "Programs and Features" - if it doesn't work through one, try the other!

Answer (score 9):

The desktop control panel one only allows you to remove desktop applications, while the setting version also allows you to uninstall the new store apps.

[image]

And [Microsoft wants to remove the desktop control panel](https://twitter.com/GabeAul/status/578018436552372224) in future Windows 10 Feature Updates. So for now you can use both to remove desktop applications, but in the future the old control panel will be gone and you can only use the settings app. With the `Windows 10 creators update`, Microsoft replaced the Programs & Features in WIN+X Menu with the settings app.

Comment: The creators update is only for Insiders right now, not the normal releases... yet. Microsoft doesn't announce an major release to everyone for Insiders to realize it's been the exact same thing they've been using for the last year. there's still about a year of bugs to be fixed before the Creators update can be viably released to everyone

Comment: @DanHolli the creators update will be released end March or April 2017 ;)

Comment: can't wait for the next announcement then:)

Answer (score 1):

Both are pre-installed in all Windows 10 installations, and you can use either, or both!  The Control Panel one is the older version, the Windows 10 settings one is newer.  There are a few differences in features and user interface.  For example:

- I find the newer one easier to use as it has a more basic layout of the apps.  Also, after clicking/tapping on an app, it shows the `modify` and `remove` options if available.
- The newer one lacks some features of the older one, but it has the ability to uninstall UWP (Universal Windows Platform) apps that are installed from the Windows Store.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, apps are for windows 10 pre-installed or store-installed apps. They do not affect or show non-win 10 or non-store installed programs. On the other hand, add or remove programs show desktop programs, which are downloaded elsewhere, or are from "Old style windows". This includes downloaded and installed programs.